# Add variable to a triple quote string issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I ran the following code below in Python:

```
configuration_str= """
    configuration={
                "query": {
                "query": "CALL `{0}.{1}.{2}`(); ",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
            },

""".format("server_name", "dataset_name", "sp_name")
```

I got the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '\n                    "query"'
```

What is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to escape the braces that _aren't_ supposed to be `str.format`ted.

Comment: Why are you appearing to generate Python code as string in the first place…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using f string

```
server_name = 'A'
dataset_name = 'B'
sp_name ='C'

configuration_str = f"""configuration={{
                "query": {{
                "query": "CALL '{server_name}.{dataset_name}.{sp_name}'(); ",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }}
            }}"""

print(configuration_str)
```

output

```
configuration={
                "query": {
                "query": "CALL 'A.B.C'(); ",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
            }
```

Comment: f-strings have the same problem as OP's code, which you just silently fixed without explanation…